# Asp.net Dropdownlist selected item value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the `SelectedItem` in the `DropDownList`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Etkin_Drop" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Etkin_Drop_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Seç" Value="-1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Aktif" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Deaktif" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

First list item value is `-1` but when I want to check in the if statement its not working

```
protected void Etkin_Drop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Etkin_Drop.SelectedItem.Value) == -1)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Lütfen Bir Seçim Yapınız');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        Label4.Text = Etkin_Drop.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}
```

I could not define the problem

Comment: How you confirmed it's not working? did you try debugging?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and check what value you are getting instead of -1?

Comment: yes I confirmed, script manager should give the warning but its not going into the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack` Property to your `DropDownList` and set this property to `True`. Like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Etkin_Drop" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="Etkin_Drop_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
```